# Working with list of lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, cartesian-product, cross-product

Please help me to solve this problem:
I have a list of lists

> [[1,2],[3,4]]

How do I get:

> [1,3]
>
> [1,4]
>
> [2,3]
>
> [2,4]

Or if I have a list of lists

> [[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]]

How do I get:

> [1,3,6]
>
> [1,3,7]
>
> [1,4,6]
>
> [1,4,7]
>
> [2,3,6]
>
> [2,3,7]
>
> [2,4,6]
>
> [2,4,7]

Comment: i believe this is called the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
lists([], []).
lists([[Head|_]|Lists], [Head|L]):-
  lists(Lists, L).
lists([[_,Head|Tail]|Lists], L):-
  lists([[Head|Tail]|Lists], L).
```

That is, take the first element of the first list in your input list and continue recursively with the remaining lists. As a second chance, skip that element and redo with the remaining elements.

Answer (score 10):

The predicate for accessing a single list element is the most basic Prolog building block: `member/2`.

And you want a list of *all lists'* elements: `maplist/3` does such mapping. Thus we can write

```
combine(Ls, Rs) :-
    maplist(get1, Ls, Rs).
get1(L, E) :-
    member(E, L).
```

note that `get1/2` is only required so that we swap the `member/2` arguments. But because in (pure) Prolog we are describing *relations between* arguments, we can swap arguments' order and simplify it even more:

```
combine(Ls, Rs) :-
    maplist(member, Rs, Ls).
```

Test output:

```
?- combine( [[1,2],[a,b]], Xs).
Xs = [1, a] ;
Xs = [1, b] ;
Xs = [2, a] ;
Xs = [2, b].

%% this is the same as:
       %% maplist( member, Xs, [[1,2],[a,b]]) :-
       %%          member( X1,  [1,2]      ),
       %%          member( X2,        [a,b]),  Xs = [X1,X2].
```

*edit*

A joke: really, my first combine/2 should have been written like

```
combine(Ls, Rs) :-
    maplist(rebmem, Ls, Rs).
rebmem(L, E) :-
    member(E, L).
```

Comment: great use of member & maplist!  very impressive!

Comment: Why this command: findall(X, maplist(member, [[a,b,c], [1,2,3]], X), L). gives infinite output?

Comment: @mso: member/2 has a list as second argument. Otherwise it 'builds up' it on backtracking, hence it doesn't terminate when driven by findall

Comment: a little gem, this thing is. :)