# Appending to a list using recursion goes into endless loop in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to append lists for every `Element` in another list but I am caught in an endless loop.

```
?- append_to_list([a, b], [1,2,3], X).

find([], E, []).
find([H|T], E, [[H, E]|Res]) :-
    find(T, E, Res).    

append_to_list(L, [], []).
append_to_list(L, [H|T], Res) :-
    find(L, H, R), 
    append(Res, R, New),
    append_to_list(L, T, New).
```

The output I would like to have with this example is:

```
X = [[a,1],[a,2],[a,3],[b,1],[b,2],[b,3]].
```

When I try to `trace` to see what I did wrong it says that it fails to exit and starts it again in an endless loop.

Why is this failing to exit?

Comment: What's the purpose of the numbers 1, 2, and 3 in `append_to_list([a], [1,2,3], X)`?

Comment: I just put an example here with random numbers, it is actually doing a lot more. But it still goes into the endless loop, with the same output.

Comment: Regardless of the specific numbers, I don't see the point of the list.

Comment: @lurker edited the question for it to be a little more understandable

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. That is a very different result than what you were previously asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this failing to exit?

Because you call `append(R, ['a', 'b'], New),` with both R and New not instantiated, and there are infinite solutions that Prolog compute on backtracking.

```
?- append(R, ['a', 'b'], New).
R = [],
New = [a, b] ;
R = [_3986],
New = [_3986, a, b] ;
R = [_3986, _3998],
New = [_3986, _3998, a, b] ;
...
```

But, I cannot see a 'logical' way to get `[a,b,a,b,a,b]` from `append_to_list([a], [1,2,3], X)`. It's easy if what you really want is `[a,a,b,a,b,a,b]`:

```
append_to_list(L, [], L).
append_to_list(L, [_|T], R) :-
    append(L, [a, b], New),
    append_to_list(New, T, R).
```

*edit*

After clarification of what's needed, I suggest to see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52886486/874024).

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that I had given enough information, but as it seems, my question was poorly phrased. I have edited the question. Is there a chance you can help me now?

Comment: Since I found an answer on the link you provided I will accept this as an answer